# Writing a variable to a text file - Python

Tags: python, file, printing

I was working on a program that has a log file and when I try to print a variable directly to the file, cmd says that it is encountering an error along the lines of "expected a character buffer object". I searched for related issues in stackoverflow and saw that I could import json (which I am trying to avoid) or I could do `str(VariableGoesHere)`. However, the variable is composed of parenthesis and commas such that it incorporates 9 arguments. When this gets printed to the file, the output contains the quotation marks, the parenthesis, and the commas. Does anyone know what buffer object it's looking for, other than str()? If it requires str(), int(), or other elements like such, is there an easy alternative? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here is the code I am using

```
f = open('C:\users\MY ANONYMOUS USERNAME\desktop\MTLog.txt', 'a')

writing = 'Range is from ', x1, ' minutes to ', y1, ' minutes. ' , 'The randomly picked time was ' , Number1, ' minutes.'

    f.write( writing ) 
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
```

Traceback (most recent calls last):
 File "MT.py", line 64, in 
  f.write( writing )
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

I am sorry that I was not very clear at first as I have only been reading stack overflow, and not posting in it.

Comment: Show your code, the exact error, and the traceback.

Comment: OK. I am really sorry about my vagueness. I am new to the forums (at least questions). I want this to print to a file, the text within "'s and the value of the variables, and have it print one sentence with punctuation that actually makes sense. Please take it off hold so that I can finish this project I am currently working on. Thanks for your time and teaching me the ways of StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open('stackoverflow.txt','w')
example = 'Hello World!'
example_two = 54
file.write(example)
file.write(str(example_two))
file.close()
```

This is how I would write to my file, using two examples, please post your code if you want further assistance other than my example.

Comment: The problem with using str() is that it adds the 's and the ,s and the ()'s. Thanks though!

Comment: Ok combine example_two into a sentence with example using ,'s and ()'s and see what it prints into the text file. Doing